# How to get lowercase letters in "idem"/"ders." abbreviation?

Tags: biblatex, capitalization, german, biblatex-dw

When citing `@inbook` if the author of the book is the same as the author of the cited text in that book, the bibliography style `authortitle-dw` recognises this and puts out "idem". In German, this is "Ders." (or "Dies." with female or multiple authors).

Now I would like to find out how I can make the abbreviation "Ders."/"Dies." appear in lower case letters. In the MWE below, I get this:

> Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich: »Rechts-, Pflichten- und Religionslehre für die Unterklasse (1810ff.)«, in: Ders.: Nürnberger und Heidelberger Schriften 1808-1817, hrsg. v. Eva Moldenhauer und Karl Markus Michel, Werke 4, 2. Aufl., Frankfurt/M. 1993, S. 204–274.

What I would like to get is this (I only used bold letters to highlight the word; I do not want the word to be bold in citations or my bibliography):

> Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich: »Rechts-, Pflichten- und Religionslehre für die Unterklasse (1810ff.)«, in: **ders.:** Nürnberger und Heidelberger Schriften 1808-1817, hrsg. v. Eva Moldenhauer und Karl Markus Michel, Werke 4, 2. Aufl., Frankfurt/M. 1993, S. 204–274.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=5cm, top=2cm, right=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}

Blablabla.\footcite[456]{RPR}

\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}, heading=bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```

Here's what's in my `mystyle.sty` file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}[2020/05/21 FUX's custom LaTeX style]

%Custom preamble

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}

%Das Nachfolgende ist der Zitationsstil mit allen seinen Optionen:

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authortitle-dw,
    useprefix=true,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    nopublisher=true,
    nolocation=false,
    citedas=true,
    citeauthorname=firstfull,
    firstfull=true,
    acronyms=true,
    idembib=true,
    idembibformat=dash,
    edbyidem=true,
    editorstring=parens,
    ibidtracker=false,
    editionstring=true,
    series=beforeedition,
    seriesformat=standard,
    shorthandinbib=false,
    terselos=true,
    pageref=false,
    loccittracker=true,
    idemtracker=false,
    shorthandwidth=105pt,
    citepages=separate,
    ]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article, inbook, incollection]
  {title}{\frqq{}#1\flqq}

%Das Nachfolgende greift auf die literatur.bib Datei zu:

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\endinput
```

And here's what's in my `literatur.bib` file:

```
@inbook{RPR,
  author      = {Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich},
  editor      = {Moldenhauer, Eva and Michel, Karl Markus},
  title       = {Rechts-, Pflichten- und Religionslehre für die Unterklasse (1810ff.\isdot)},
  options     = {acronym=true},
  shorthand   = {RPR},
  booktitle   = {Nürnberger und Heidelberger Schriften 1808-1817},
  bookauthor  = {Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich},
  year        = {1993},
  edition     = 2,
  series      = {Werke},
  number      = {4},
  publisher   = {Suhrkamp},
  address     = {Frankfurt/M.},
  pages       = {204-274},
  keywords    = {Hegel},
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I took the liberty of adding two tags that are relevant to, and in fact at the root of, your issue – as you can also see in my answer.

Comment: did the proposed solution work for you? Please consider accepting the answer (the green "checkmark" symbol) if it solved your issue.

Comment: Dear marquinho, yes, it worked perfectly and moreover your analysis was very interesting to read. I now accepted your answer (I hadn't seen the checkmark symbol before). Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: You're welcome and – thank you for the opportunity to learn more about biblatex! It's really fascinating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a surprisingly tricky one! It took me some digging, but here's (1) an explanation of why the problem arises (which I would call a small bug in the current version of `authortitle-dw`) and (2) a couple of possible solutions.

### Cause of the bug

As you pointed out,

> When citing `@inbook` if the author of the book is the same as the author of the cited text in that book, the bibliography-style `authortitle-dw` recognises this and puts out [the bibstring] `idem`

which in the German localization is realized as “dieselbe”/“dies.” (modulo gender). Note that the string, by itself, is in lowercase. Though it **can be** capitalized after the right kinds of *punctuation* (typically, at the beginning of a sentence).

Additionally, it appears that the author(s) of `authortitle-dw` had exactly your situation in mind and stipulated that “ders.” and the like should appear in lowercase at this specific point of an `inbook` publication. This is the code from `authortitle-dw.bbx`:

```
%% 'Ders.' bei inbook, wenn gleicher Autor
\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {\ifbool{bbx:edbyidem}
      {\midsentence*\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield{gender}}\addcolon}
      {\printnames[byauthor]{bookauthor}%
       \newunit\newblock}}
    {\printnames[byauthor]{bookauthor}%
     \newunit\newblock}}
```

Note that when `author` and `bookauthor` are identical, the bibstring `idem` is used *and is preceded by* the `biblatex` command `\midsentence`. Its function (with or without star) is the following: “A localisation string immediately after this command will not be capitalized” ([biblatex documentation, §4.7.6](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=278)).

Since we are (**it seems**) mid-sentence, we expect that the strings “dies.” and friends should appear in lowercase. But fun fact: No.

The ultimate reason is *the treatment of colons in the German localization*. Specifically, of the colon right before “ders.” (the inclusion bibmacro `in:` ends with the punctuation command `\intitlepunct`, which in turn is defined as `\addcolon\space`, as expected).

The main biblatex localization for German (`german.lbx`), via the rule `\DeclareCapitalPunctuation` (see the [documentation, §4.7.5](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=277)), dictates the capitalization of phrases directly following a colon. We are **really not** in mid-sentence.

```
\DeclareCapitalPunctuation{:.!?}
```

This is unlike the standard (English) `biblatex` specs (`\DeclareCapitalPunctuation{:.!?}`). It is also debatable and too broad, because in German only *complete sentences* are capitalized after a colon (per [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D93)) – but it is the law of the land nevertheless.

Now, `biblatex-dw` inherits this behavior from root `biblatex` – <s>meaning that the author(s), by not changing this part of the specification, effectively nullified their own use of `\midsentence` in the situation at hand.</s>

**EDIT**: To be fair to `biblatex-dw`, this mechanism used to work when the package was last updated (2016) and `\midsentence*` in the macro from `biblatex-dw` produced the desired effect. In late 2019, `biblatex` v3.15 changed the way `\intitlepunct` is handled, effectively nullifying the effect of `\midsentence*` in this case, because now `\midsentence*` comes in too early.
Thanks to @moewe for pointing this out in the comments.

(For a test, put a copy of `german-dw.lbx` in latex's search path and add `\DeclareBibliographyExtras{\DeclareCapitalPunctuation{.!?}}`; the capitalization problem disappears.)

### Solutions

(**EDIT**: Thanks to @moewe for pointing out solution (C) in the comments.)
I can envision three solutions; in order of increasing  generality, these are:

(A) Edit/patch the macro `bybookauthor` so that the bibstring `idem` is never capitalized (for this, biblatex offers the command `\bibncpstring`: “Similar to `\bibstring` but the term is never capitalized. ”, [§4.8](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=279)).

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{bybookauthor}
    {\bibstring[\mkidem]}
    {\bibncpstring[\mkidem]}{}{}
```

(B) Edit the command `\intitlepunct` to restore the desired case, i.e., `\midsentence`.

```
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\midsentence\space}
```

The advantage of (B) over (A) is its generality: it comes to bear in all sorts of cases, not just `inbook` publications.

(C) Revert to biblatex's standard punctuation rule and disable *all and any* automatic capitalization following `:`.

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclareCapitalPunctuation{.!?}}
```

Because of its general scope, this solution might have unintended consequences. If this is your desired outcome, note that it is your responsibility to apply capitalization where it is required (per Duden).

In this MWE, uncomment any one of the three solutions to get the desired result.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{literatur.bib}
@inbook{RPR,
  author      = {Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich},
  title       = {Rechts-, Pflichten- und Religionslehre für die Unterklasse (1810ff.\isdot)},
  booktitle   = {Nürnberger und Heidelberger Schriften 1808-1817},
  bookauthor  = {Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}


%% Solution (A)
%\usepackage{xpatch}     % required for \xpatchbibmacro
%\xpatchbibmacro{bybookauthor}
%    {\bibstring[\mkidem]}
%    {\bibncpstring[\mkidem]}{}{}

%% Solution (B)
%\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\midsentence\space}

%% Solution (C)
%\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclareCapitalPunctuation{.!?}}

\begin{document}
\cite{RPR}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: bibliography with entry in the correct lowercase]

Comment: Very nice analysis! To be fair to `biblatex-dw`, the `\midsentence*` used to work as intended until `biblatex` v3.15 when printing of `\intitlepunct` was handed over to the punctuation tracker (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/6271f7c884a5b8efce28eb3934fae89e7a57007b). This means that the `\midsentence*` now comes in too early, because `\intitlepunct` is effectively only printed by `\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield{gender}}`.

Comment: It is implied in the answer, but another solution would be to say `\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclareCapitalPunctuation{.!?}}`. Of course this has the potential to change the capitalisation after other colons (and not just the "in:"), but that might be desirable.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks a lot for the information! and (indirect) apologies to the maker of `biblatex-dw`. I edited my answer accordingly and have also included the solution via `\DefineBibliographyExtras`. I was wrongly assuming that this command was only available in the localization files (as is the case with `\DeclareBibliographyStrings`). Thanks!

Comment: Ah yeah, the situation with the various `\Declare...`/`\Define...` macros can be a bit confusing. `\DeclareBibliographyExtras` and `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` are only available in the `.lbx` file, but `\DefineBibliographyExtras{<language>}` and `\DefineBibliographyStrings{<language>}` are also available in the preamble (in case of the strings with slightly different behaviour).